# Options Aren't Showing Up until I click the select element in iPad Safari Browser (Multi Select Form)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, browser, safari

I have a multi select form element:

Code:

```
<select  id="something" name ="something" onchange="something();" multiple="multiple" >
<option value="something">something</option>
<option value="somethingelse">something else</option>
</select>
```

On the ipad, the options aren't showing until I click the select element. Before I do that it says "0 Items".

Any idea why? How to fix this? (BTW it works normally on a computer browser (IE, FF, Safari, Chrome, just not on the ipad)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the default behavior of Multi Select in iOS browser, it shows the number of selected items ( 0 on first load) try selecting some and the number of selected items will then be displayed.